# mariadb crashses very often

Tags: crash, mariadb

Mysql mariaDB crashes frequently and I cannot find out why. I have installed MariaDB a couple of times but in vain.

Increased `innodb_buffer_pool_size` to 60% of memory space. As I was getting Host name could not be resolved, included skip name resolve in my.cnf file, but in vain.

```
2019-09-30 21:46:14 140285622676608 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
2019-09-30 21:46:14 140285622676608 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2019-09-30 21:46:14 140285622676608 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2019-09-30 21:46:14 140285622676608 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
2019-09-30 21:46:14 140285622676608 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2019-09-30 21:46:14 140285622676608 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2019-09-30 21:46:14 140285622676608 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE crc32 instructions
2019-09-30 21:46:14 140285622676608 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 3.0G
2019-09-30 21:46:14 140285622676608 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2019-09-30 21:46:14 140285622676608 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2019-09-30 21:46:14 140285622676608 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2019-09-30 21:46:14 140285622676608 [Note] InnoDB:  Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.6.44-86.0 started; log sequence number 901877131
2019-09-30 21:46:14 140281617807104 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) not yet started
2019-09-30 21:46:14 140285622676608 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2019-09-30 21:46:14 140285622676608 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
2019-09-30 21:46:14 140285622676608 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '10.1.41-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.18.04.1'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  Ubuntu 18.04
2019-10-01  0:22:33 140285573568256 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Normal shutdown
2019-10-01  0:22:33 140285573568256 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
2019-10-01  0:22:33 140281651377920 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
2019-10-01  0:22:33 140285573568256 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
2019-10-01  0:22:34 140285573568256 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for page_cleaner to finish flushing of buffer pool
2019-10-01  0:22:35 140285573568256 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 1007730801
2019-10-01  0:22:35 140285573568256 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

Any suggestions how I can stop mariadb from crashing?

Comment: That looks like a normal shutdown of a MariaDB server when done via `systemctl stop mariadb` or `mysqladmin shutdown`. Make sure nothing is stopping it (backups etc.).

Comment: @marksujm, thank for your guidance. let me check....

Comment: How much RAM?..